# Is there a way to get metamask assets info using web3?

Tags: reactjs, web3js, metamask

In web3 we call `web3.eth.getAccounts()` or `window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })` to list the accounts in **metamask**, is there any specific method we could call to get the registered tokens/assets in **metamask**?